# How do I turn off my Minecraft server announcing things in chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently my server has been announcing the most random things in chat and I don't know how to turn it off.  It has been announcing the time, the date, and everytime a player gets kicked for being AFK. (Which is only visible to staff by default.) I'm running PaperSpigot on a  1.16 server. Thank you for any and all help.

[image]

[image: Pictures of the event occuring]

Comment: What plugins are you using?

Comment: I'm using these - https://i.imgur.com/mmEEOSJ.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the plugins' configuration files and make sure that any chat messages are disabled. For example, it seems like the AFK message could be a result of the AdvancedAFK plugin.

Comment: Yep, I fixed the AFK one. I just have no idea what to do for the time. It also says the current date too